# SQL: how to get a weighted count using GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, mysql, frequency-analysis

How can I make a query like:

```
select myvalue, count() as freq from mytable group by myvalue;
```

But where `freq` sums values from a `weight` column instead of counting each row as 1?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select myvalue, sum(weight) as freq from mytable group by myvalue;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [Sum](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php) aggregate function to handle this.

```
SELECT MyValue, Sum(weight) AS Total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY myvalue;
```

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

```
select myvalue, SUM(weight) as freq from mytable group by myvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sum(weight) as freq` in your select query